# Is the Camel ActiveMQ producer Template thread safe?

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to implement a message producer behind a REST interface.  The message producer uses the request/reply pattern.  When reading the documentation for the Camel producer it is noted that only one producer should be created per application.

Is the producer thread safe so that I can call the send method from multiple threads?  Will it work properly when several concurrent requests are waiting for their related replies?  How would it be best implemented using Spring, Tomcat and Jersey?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes both the producer and consumer template in Apache Camel is thread safe.

And yeah the request/reply works properly. How it is implemented is a mix between the Camel routing engine, and the components that are being used.

eg REST and JMS works a bit differently. Where JMS will use separate message queues to pickup replies, which has a JMSCorrelationID that is used for correlating reply messages.

Where as REST is usually a sync call due the sync nature of HTTP. But it depends on the underlying component, as some supports async communication on the http client such as camel-jetty, camel-ahc etc.

Comment: Thank you Claus for confirming that for me, I suspected that it was but I had to be sure, I work in the paranoid world of financial systems.  Yes I was aware of the variances in the request reply between classical REST oriented architecture and Camel/ActiveMQ.  My REST interface actually uses a mix of the sync and async response types depending on the performance of the integrated system(s) in the background and the client's settings as presented in headers.  Camel is just brilliant as is your book [link](http://amzn.com/1935182366).  Thank you.

Comment: I updated the javadoc on the ProducerTemplate and ConsumerTemplate with a note about the thread-safety. So people may find this information easier in the future from the javadoc API

Comment: Hi @ClausIbsen,  I have found that calling producertemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders("http4://host:port/endpoint"..) with multiple interleaved threads creates lot of PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager. This makes me think if producer template is really thread safe.